# Why my elements size fixer code always increases elemens size when it originally set to 100%?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, size

I am writing a general IE8 - IE10 hack for fixing elements size when using `<!doctype html />`, so I will never ever need to write a lot of CSS junk just to make layout that I need.
I mean this (like div's width and height were never set to 100%):

[image]

So, I coded this:

```
<!doctype html />
<html style = "height: 100%;">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
        <title>test size fixer</title>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function endsWith(str, suffix)
            {
                if (!str)
                    return false;

                return str.toString().indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) >= 0;
            }

            //recursively calculating elemens sizes based on their parents sizes
            function fixDimensionsRecursiveIn(start_elem)
            {
                if (!document || !document.body)
                    return;

                var curr_elem = start_elem ? start_elem : document.body;

                //currently fixing size for this containers only
                if (curr_elem.tagName.toLowerCase() == "div" || curr_elem.tagName.toLowerCase() == "table")
                {
                    var curr_w = curr_elem.width || curr_elem.style.width; //determine current size
                    var curr_h = curr_elem.height || curr_elem.style.height;
                    var parent_w = curr_elem.parentNode.clientWidth || curr_elem.parentNode.offsetWidth; //determine element parent rendered size
                    var parent_h = curr_elem.parentNode.clientHeight || curr_elem.parentNode.offsetHeight;

                    var w_fixed = false; //if size were fixed at first step
                    var h_fixed = false;

                    var new_width = null; //new calculates sizes based on parent element
                    var new_height = null;

                    if (endsWith(curr_w, "%") && parent_w > 0) //if current element size set with %
                    {
                        curr_elem.original_width = curr_w; //saving original width into new field
                        curr_w = curr_w.substr(0, curr_w.length - 1); //removing % for calculations
                        new_width = (curr_w * parent_w) / 100; //calculating the width of this element based on parent's width
                        curr_elem.style.width = Math.floor(new_width) + "px"; //applying new width to current element

                        w_fixed = true; //setting flag that we no need to fix width for this elem anymore
                    }

                    if (endsWith(curr_h, "%") && parent_h > 0) //same, but for height
                    {
                        curr_elem.original_height = curr_h;
                        curr_h = curr_h.substr(0, curr_h.length - 1);
                        new_height = (curr_h * parent_h) / 100;
                        curr_elem.style.height = Math.floor(new_height) + "px";

                        h_fixed = true;
                    }

                    //so, at first we replaced % size with px size, but we somehow need to resize elements later
                    //that's why we saved original sizes into new field. Now we retrieve it and use for next calculations
                    var possible_original_width = curr_elem.original_width;
                    var possible_original_height = curr_elem.original_height;

                    if (!w_fixed && endsWith(possible_original_width, "%") && parent_w > 0) //if elem width wasn't fixed at first step, then it means it already swapped % size with calculated px size
                    {
                        possible_original_width = possible_original_width.substr(0, possible_original_width.length - 1); //removing % from size
                        new_width = (possible_original_width * parent_w) / 100; //calculating new size
                        curr_elem.style.width = Math.floor(new_width) + "px"; //applying it
                    }

                    if (!h_fixed && endsWith(possible_original_height, "%") && parent_h > 0)
                    {
                        possible_original_height = possible_original_height.substr(0, possible_original_height.length - 1);
                        new_height = (possible_original_height * parent_h) / 100;
                        curr_elem.style.height = Math.floor(new_height) + "px";
                    }
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < curr_elem.children.length; i++) //fixing sizes for it's children
                    fixDimensionsRecursiveIn(curr_elem.children[i]);
            }

            setInterval(fixDimensionsRecursiveIn, 500);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style = "height: 100%; margin: 0px;">
        <table border = "1" width = "100%" height = "100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan = "2" height = "1px">header</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width = "40%" align = "center" valign = "middle" style = "background-color: Silver;">
                    <div style = 'width: 100%; height: 100%; border: dashed;'>should be 100% of silver cell</div>
                </td>
                <td>text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan = "2" height = "1px">bottom panel</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the problem is that when any element size is set to 100%, it keeps growing at every size fix call. I even tried to reduce calculated size by 1 and 2 pixels, but it still grows.

[image]

I need to understand why it grows... First I thought it's because of wrong calculations, then I ever tried to apply Math.floor, but that didn't help.

Comment: `table-layout: fixed` set to `table` might help? You should also prefer CSS instead of attributes.

Comment: @Teemu - This will not solve the problem in general. The layout I showed is only an example of children element wrong size calculation.

Comment: Please note that an attribute like `height="1px"` is an error. Attributes do not take `px` suffixes! You are much better off using styles. Anyway, I can't test here, but you can try inserting `curr_elem.height = '';` before the `curr_elem.style.height = ...;` statements. I found that doing that fixes things in some cases.

Comment: @MrLister - Thank for pointing on wrong `px` usage. Also, setting sizes to `''` didn't helped.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Added `console.log` to see the values in each step/comparison to see why it could be failing? Also (and this is more out of curiosity), why? Is this just for testing? I find it difficult to understand the purpose or utility of this code (that btw is far from valid)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro - I debugged it, but I don't understand why it increases size at every step. It's like whole `body` originally had 500, 400 size and then on next step started to have 507, 407 size, and etc, and etc and etc, but the calculations of new element sizes are correct. The purpose of the code to fix element size that for some "only God know reason" has `minimal to fit inner content` size, while it's size set to some percents.